# How to Join to tables for each row of the other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, left-join

I am converting some old code to get it more optimize so i stuck here i can do it as old way by firing 2 stored procedures but i was thinking if it is possible with the join i tried but couldn't get it right so any help would be great

My old code and queries

```
dataset = Select data1,data2,data3 from table where column1='somevalue'
//now consider dataset have the records of the above query then 

  foreach (row in dataset)
  {
     Select top 1 tab2data,tab2data from table2 with (nolock) where LtrFileName = row.data1
     //Do some more functionality i can handle this part 
  }
```

so i was trying to combine these two queries by join i got it right with left join but i can't figure out about the `top 1` it gives wrong output if apply it with the join .so basically i am asking is there a way to get these two queries into one stored procedure and avoid all the foreach coding part .

**UPDATE**
Sorry if i am not clear but here is original output from first query it gives

```
 data1      data2    data3   data4
 001000     002142  NBIS1N  20130514
 001000     002142  NBIS1R  20130514
 001000     002142  NBTB1N  20130514
 001000     002142  NBTB1R  20130514
```

these are all the records

```
  tab2data1             tab2data2            data3  tab2data3 
    NULL                NULL                NBIS1N  239
NBIS1R_20100323.pdf 000110-Acct_Rec_Mgmt    NBIS1R  349
NBIS1R_20100324.pdf 000110-Acct_Rec_Mgmt    NBIS1R  349
NBTB1N_20100323.pdf 000110-Acct_Rec_Mgmt    NBTB1N  508
NBTB1N_20100324.pdf 000110-Acct_Rec_Mgmt    NBTB1N  508
 NULL               NULL                    NBTB1R  1360
```

now after the executing the second query i get the only four rows as below

```
 tab2data1             tab2data2            data3  tab2data3 
    NULL                   NULL             NBIS1N  239
NBIS1R_20100324.pdf 000110-Acct_Rec_Mgmt    NBIS1R  349
NBTB1N_20100324.pdf 000110-Acct_Rec_Mgmt    NBTB1N  508
      NULL                  NULL            NBTB1R  1360
```

Comment: Use the database to join the tables instead of loading all into memory first.

Comment: I tried join with left join but it gives the 2 rows of table2 and i want only top 1 that where i got stuck

Comment: How are these tables linked, through `data3`?

Comment: I've edited my answer below. I assume the last result above is your desired result, isn't it?

Comment: Yes that is the result i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.data1, t1.data2, t1.data3, t2.tab2data
FROM dbo.table1 t1 
INNER JOIN dbo.table2 t2
    ON t1.data1 = t2.LtrFileName 
WHERE t1.column1 = 'somevalue'
```

If you have multiple `table2` rows and you want just one you have to specify which you want to see. Therefore use an `Order By`. For example with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t1.data1, t1.data2, t1.data3, t2.tab2data1, t2.tab2data2, t2.tab2data3, 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.data3 ORDER BY t2.tab2data3 ASC)
    FROM dbo.table1 t1 
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 t2
        ON t1.data3 = t2.data3 
    WHERE t1.data1 = '001000'
)
SELECT data1, data2, data3, tab2data1, tab2data2, tab2data3
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Here is a demo with your new sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a032e/8/0

```
DATA1   DATA2   DATA3   TAB2DATA1            TAB2DATA2                TAB2DATA3
1000    2142    NBIS1N   (null)                (null)                   239
1000    2142    NBIS1R   NBIS1R_20100323.pdf    000110-Acct_Rec_Mgmt    349
1000    2142    NBTB1N   NBTB1N_20100323.pdf    000110-Acct_Rec_Mgmt    508
1000    2142    NBTB1R   (null)                (null)                   1360
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, I think you can get the top 1 records using `row_number()` function with `CTE` as below;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE yourProcedureName
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @yourParameter Varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

    ;with cte as (
       Select tab2data,tab2data,..., row_number() over (order by t2.LtrFileName) rn
       from table1 t1 join table2 t2
                 on t1.data1 = t2.LtrFileName
       where t1.column1 = @yourParameter
    )

    Select * 
    From cte
    Where rn = 1
END
```